# gdaltransform v3.4.1 rejects prf file accepted by v2.3.1

Tags: gdal

Moving from a PC using gdaltransform version 2.3.1 to one using 3.4.1 (Ubuntu 22.04),
gdaltransform now fails with "ERROR 1: missing [  ERROR 1: Translating source or target SRS failed: "
for a prf file which

1. Worked with version 2.3.1
2. Has no unmatching brackets I can find (first checked number of each, then to check possible misplacement removed bracket-by-bracket but all brackets matched)

Specifically the command is

`gdaltransform  -s_srs '+proj=longlat +datum=NAD83' -t_srs file.prf`

with prf file file

```
PROJCS[unnamed,   
      GEOGCS[unnamed ellipse,   
          DATUM[unknown,  
              SPHEROID[unnamed,6378137,0]],   
          PRIMEM[Greenwich,0],   
          UNIT[degree,0.0174532925199433]],   
      PROJECTION[Mercator_2SP],   
      PARAMETER[standard_parallel_1,0],   
      PARAMETER[central_meridian,0],    
      PARAMETER[false_easting,0],   
      PARAMETER[false_northing,0],   
      UNIT[metre,1,   
         AUTHORITY[EPSG,9001]]]
```

Do not understand this, seems so simple have to wonder if missing something obvious.  Looking for an explanation, in case something did change in the new version, some change in accepted format, ... ?

Should note this is for ubuntu-library GDAL.  Perhaps I should try to build GDAL myself (as I did for the previous version).  Will add that several other GDAL programs from the new 3.4.1 ubuntu libary *are* working successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GDAL seems to truncate the input at the space in **unnamed ellipse**. Use double quotes or underline. GDAL itself seems to use double quotes around all strings. This is how GDAL converts your file into simple WKT format:

```
gdalsrsinfo prjtest.prj -o wkt_simple

PROJCS["unnamed",
    GEOGCS["unnamed_ellipse",
        DATUM["unknown",
            SPHEROID["unnamed",6378137,0]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Mercator_2SP"],
    PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1]]
```

With the -V flag gdalsrsinfo reports `Validate Fails - SRS is not well formed` but I did not study that any further.

The coordinate systems handling in GDAL was largely rewritten for GDAL version 3.0 in 2019 https://gdalbarn.com/. The more strict parsing of WKT is probably due to this improvement.

Comment: Thanks for the solution!  FYI traced the problem back to my passing gdal output through a shell command, which removed the quotes.  Was on wrong track due to error implying it was a bracket problem.

Comment: PS: also make the obvious comment that the new version is less tolerant than older ones.